# Programmatically Insert Custom View in LinearLayout, Stretch It and Make it Square

Tags: android, android-view, pie-chart

I have a `LinearLayout` (holder), which has `match_parent` for both width and height. In this holder I insert a `View` (a Class extending `View`). I do this inside the `onCreate` method of the Activity.

My question is, how do I make this child `View` stretch maximum horizontally and vertically, keeping a square shape, to fill as much area as possible from the parent LinearLayout?

Here's what I use right now as a starting point:

```
    pieContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pie_container_id);
    pie = new PieView(this);
    pieContainer.addView(pie);
```

I have tried playing around with overwriting the onMeasure method on both sides (the main activity and the `PieView` class), but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this custom SquareView

```
public class SquareView extends View {
  public SquareView(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public SquareView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
  }

  public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = Math.min(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
    setMeasuredDimension(size, size);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could get the width of the entire screen

```
DisplayMetrics display = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics( display );
int screenW = display.widthPixels;
```

and set the width of the `View` to `fill_parent` and the height of the `View` to `screenW`

Maybe something like:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, screenW); // (width, height)
yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Or I might have entirely misunderstood your question. It's late here and i'm tired :) Sorry if that is the case.

Let me know if it worked or not :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not useable since I am not extending `Activity` but `View`. Thus, the `getWindowManager()` is not available.